# Is it possible to take the table level backup in mysql using any of the script?

Tags: mysql, backup, scripting, mysqladmin

I am new to MySQL and I am in need of the script which is taking backup of  multiple tables from the multiple databases in single file in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

To dump only specific tables from a database, name them on the command line following the database name:

`mysqldump my_database table1 table3 table5 > dump.sql`

To dump only specific tables from multiple database, use mysqldump again, but append to the end of the previously created file:

`mysqldump my_database2 table1 table3 table5 >> dump.sql` Note the `>>` sign

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228116/mysqldump-tables-from-different-databases

Comment: Thanks for the response Vladimir and is there any script to automate this thing

Comment: you should try atleast first  . No one can give you ready and cooked food to eat. We can give you items to cook